# Plotly R: arrange odd number of plots in subplot() function

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to arrange `3 plots` into `subplot` function, but it always divides the panel in equal parts. I would like to have something like this:[image]

But, instead, I'm getting something like this:

```
library(plotly)
subplot(plot_ly(), plot_ly(), plot_ly(), nrows = 2)
```

[image]

Is there any way to make the 3rd plot **fill the whole 2nd line?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to subplot the top row and then combine that with the bottom row.

```
library(plotly)
subplot(subplot(plot_ly(), plot_ly(), nrows = 1), plot_ly(), nrows = 2)
```

[image]